# Page content relative to tileable background

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a tileable background but I want to position elements based on tile pattern. 
For example: I have (2x)times tile from top, (2x)times tile from left from first div, (1x)time tile between two divs.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please show your code and what you've tried already.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6mzh807s/